# Why can't I display <ul> element using jQuery show method?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this `<ul>` element:

```
<ul id="inspectorMenu" class="nav pull-left" style="visibility: hidden;">
    <li style="display: inline-block;text-align: center; max-height:35px;">
        <a class="navbar-brand" ui-sref="sites.list" style="padding: 11px 09px;" title="אתרים">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tree-conifer"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li style="display: inline-block;text-align: center;max-height:35px;">
        <a class="navbar-brand" ui-sref="sitesDamages.sitesList" style="padding: 11px 09px;" title="אירועים">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

At some point I call this jQuery row to show the `<ul>` element:

```
$("#inspectorMenu").show();
```

But the `<ul>` element is not displayed.

Any idea why the `<ul>` element is not displayed? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I dont know if anybody has mentioned this yet or not but jQuery has made some big changes to hide/show because of the inconsistencies with them.

Comment: If you don't want to change your code, use `$("#inspectorMenu").css("visibility", "visible")`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JQuery's `show` is approximately the same as adding the css "display: block".  Thus, the visibility on your `ul` will still be pertinent.  Consider using "display: none" and then you can use `.show()` to show it.

```js
$("#showMe").on("click", function(){
  $("#inspectorMenu").show()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="inspectorMenu" class="nav pull-left" style="display: none;">
  <li style="display: inline-block;text-align: center; max-height:35px;"><a class="navbar-brand" ui-sref="sites.list" style="padding: 11px 09px;" title="אתרים"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tree-conifer">Some Text</i></a>
  </li>
  <li style="display: inline-block;text-align: center;max-height:35px;"><a class="navbar-brand" ui-sref="sitesDamages.sitesList" style="padding: 11px 09px;" title="אירועים"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign">Some More Text</i></a>
  </li>
</ul>

<button id="showMe">Show Me</button>
```

Answer (score 7):

you may have to change `visibility` from `hidden` to `visible` to display the element